# How to find any programmatic way to exporting an annotation table to SHP file with special column - element-

Tags: gis, shapefile

I have a problem with converting an [annotation](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/data/annotation/annotation.htm) feature table to a shape file in ORACLE database.

Basically, i want these shape files as a recovery backup for import the file to a database.

I have no problem with normal sde tables to shp files except an annotation type in case of exporting an annotation table with an 'ELEMENT' column.

I have no idea what the 'ELEMENT' column of an annotation feature table in ORACLE is.
It seems that this table has a special column called 'ELEMENT' which is a blob type.

I didn't find  to any programmatic way export a shape file with that column.

I've tried the geotools or ArcMap to export shape file with no luck

[image]

Here are some facts:

1. No problem with exporting an annotation table to a geodatabase file(gdb)
2. No problem with exporting an annotation table to a shape file(.shp) but,
3. After that the 'ELEMENT' column is not existing when reading the dbf file in the shape file.

So, is there way to export all columns of the annotation feature table to a shape file including the 'ELEMENT' column?

Any suggestion or answer will be appreciated

Find programmatic way export a shape file.

Comment: A `blob` is just a chunk of binary data so there is no way to export it into a shapefile, there are a lot of other problems with this plan too all your attribute names and types are subject to change. Why not make a proper database backup?

Comment: well. @Ian Turton, I need to analyze some part of data in the spatial table  programmatic way especially the annotation type...  currently i don't have privilege to export because of security issue.. but we all know 'the_geom' type  as a blob type. so why only one column can be binary in the shape file? that is where my question starts.

Comment: because the geometries are stored in the `.shp` file while the attributes are stored in the `,dbf` file using an obsolete DBASE III format.

Comment: thanks. @Ian Turton,, i got an idea from your answer...I guess i have to save that kind of columns in an another format of data separately from shp file when restoring it to the database with the data.